# why does a linear transformation (matrix) have a right inverse only if the transformation represented by the matrix is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question assumes that a matrix with a right inverse must have at least as many rows as columns; how can I see that too?

EDIT - corrected the question to say "right inverse"

Comment: Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb F$. If the map $\mathbb F^n \ni x \mapsto Ax \in \mathbb F^m$ is onto, and $e_1,\dots,e_m$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb F^m$, then there exists $x_1,\dots,x_m$ in $\mathbb F^n$ such that $Ax_j = e_j$. Now let $B$ be the matrix whose $j$-th column is $x_j$. Check that $AB = I$.

Comment: That seems to say that if A is onto, then it has a right identity. Does it also say that if A is not onto it does not have a right identity?   What you wrote is essentially the problem immediately preceding the one I posted (in the textbook).   I feel I understand the procedure for finding the right identity, but cannot prove that the  existence of a right identity implies A is onto.

Comment: @cumin Do you mean a right **inverse** rather than right identity?

Comment: Yes, i meant to say right inverse; I am will edit the question. Thank you pointing that out.

Comment: Actually, *every* onto function has a right inverse. This really has nothing to do with linear transformations. Suppose $f$ maps $X$ onto $Y$. For each $y\in Y$, define $S_y=\{x\in X:f(x)=y\}$. Since $f$ is surjective, each $S_y$ is nonempty. Let $g:Y\to X$ be any function satisfying $g(y)\in S_y$ for all $y\in Y$. Then, $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$.

Comment: Note however that the above proof uses the axiom of choice.

Comment: Thanks; I am trying to understand why a function/matrix that is not onto does not have a right inverse. I think I am closing in on: AB = I --> ABx = Ix = x for any x, so for any x there is a Bx such that ABx = x

Comment: @cumin: Again, you can think of this purely in terms of functions. If $f:X\to Y$ has a right-inverse, then by assumption there is a function $g:Y\to X$ satisfying $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$, and so $f$ is onto. Hence, if $f$ is *not* onto, then it doesn't have a right-inverse (as if it did have a right-inverse, then it would be onto).

Comment: OK, I think I see. Since g is a function, it must do something with (i.e. map) everything in its domain; it can't overlook anything.  The original problem was stated in terms of the number of rows compared to the number of columns in a matrix, and I find that tangibility both helpful and frustrating.